# keep focus on Tippy.js when click button into tooltip with angular and Fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, angular, fullcalendar, tippyjs

i need a suggestion about fullcalendar and tippyjs (https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/).
so, this is my event into fullcalendar:

[image]

so as you can see when mouseover on event i show the tippy js like this:

```
  eventMouseEnter(ev: any) {
console.log('eventMouseEnter: ', ev.el);
const template = document.getElementById('template');
tippy(ev.el, {
  content: template.innerHTML,
  allowHTML: true,
  interactive: true,
  interactiveBorder: 30,
  zIndex: 999999999999999999999999,
  theme: 'light'
})
```

}

this is my html code:

```
<div id="template" tabindex="0">
  <div class="tippy-box" tabindex="0">
    <button mat-raised-button tabindex="0">button</button>
    <span tabindex="0">
      <select>
        <option>one</option>
      </select>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

the problem is, i can't get click on button, or select...every click my event return is on fullcalendar event, but not tippy js button...
how can i solve this? I need to have the click focus only on tooltip of tippy js when open.

THanks

Comment: Have you tried calling `stopPropagation`? on event?

Comment: where do apply?

Comment: Did I get it right, once you click on button or select, toopltip is closed, and then in some code triggers event of calendar?

Comment: THe tooltip keep open but the event run on fullcalendar